# issue while creating a pair RDD in spark from text file and applying reduceByKey

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

To run some simple spark transformation given in learning Spark  i need to create one pair RDD

(example: {(1, 2), (3, 4), (3, 6)})

What is the best way to create this so I can use groupByKey() etc on this.  I tried putting this in a file and reading by below code but some how this doesn't work

Text file content

```
1 2

3 4

3 6
```

Code

```
val lines = sc.textFile("path_to_file")

val pairs = lines.map(x => (x.split(" ")(0), x))

pairs.foreach(println)
```

It prints as below

```
scala> pairs.foreach(println)
(1,1 2)
(3,3 4)
(3,3 6)
```

While I want it as

```
1 2

3 4

3 6
```

Is there any easier way to do this in scala ?

Comment: in `(x.split(" ")(0), x)` the second element of the tuple is the original string (`x`), hence the result.

Comment: guys please do not vote negative , its a genuine question and we had this while going through learning spark book chapter 4.  It takes while to figure this out so

Answer (score 1):

Split the text file content based on index for both key and value to generate a pair RDD.

```
val pairs = lines.map(x => (x.split(" ")(0), (x.split(" ")(1)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay Vignesh! But that doesn't give the expected  output. As you can see , it mixing 46  output                                               scala> pairs.reduceByKey((x,y) => x +y).foreach(println)
(3,46)
(1,2)

Comment: this is what I am running                                                                                    scala> pairs.reduceByKey((x,y) => x +y).foreach(println)
(3,46)
(1,2)

scala> pairs.groupByKey().foreach(println)
(3,CompactBuffer(4, 6))
(1,CompactBuffer(2))

scala>

Comment: You took the file content as your RDD value, and don't try to print every time with println use collect(). Try this out. val lines = sc.textFile("path_to_file")
val pairs = lines.map(x => (x.split(" ")(0), (x.split(" ")(1)))
val redbykey = pairs.reduceByKey((x, y) => x + y)
redbykey.collect()

Comment: its still combining scala> pairs.reduceByKey((x,y) => x +y).collect()
res79: Array[(String, String)] = Array((3,46), (1,2))

Comment: also is there any alternate way to create this instead of reading from file , that should be also acceptable for now , i mainly want to run all those functions like reduceByKey  on this so

Comment: use a parallelize with a list. val createpair = sc.parallelize(List((10, 20), (11, 21), (12, 22))).

Comment: Your file input should also work try splitting with , and add , to your file. May be you have some additional spaces in your file.

Comment: No luck , I changed to commas                                                                 scala> val pairs = lines.map(x => (x.split(",")(0),(x.split(",")(1)) ))
pairs: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)] = MapPartitionsRDD[114] at map at <console>:23

scala> pairs.foreach(println)
(1,2)
(3,4)
(3,6)

scala> pairs.reduceByKey((x,y) => x+y).foreach(println)
(3,46)
(1,2)

Comment: Your RDD is a string, RDD[(String, String)] hence it is just appending the values. try creating with parallelize you will get integer RDD and then try.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
scala> val pairsRDD = lines.flatMap { x => 
           x.split("""\s+""") match {
                case Array(a,b) => Some((a,b))
                case _ => None
           }
       }
pairsRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)] = MapPartitionsRDD[21] at flatMap at <console>:23

scala> val pairs = pairsRDD.collect
pairs: Array[(String, String)] = Array((1,2), (3,4), (3,6))

scala> pairs foreach println
(1,2)
(3,4)
(3,6)
```

NOTE: If you want the values a numeric instead of `String`, just add type conversion ( `.toInt` , `.toDouble` etc ).

Comment: See `NOTE:` in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for reply , Here is the solution that worked for me

val lines = sc.textFile("path to file ")

val pairs = lines.keyBy( line => (line.split(" ")(0))).mapValues( line => line.split(" ") (1).trim.toInt)

pairs.reduceByKey((x,y) => x+y).foreach(println)

scala> pairs.reduceByKey((x,y) => x+y).foreach(println)

(3,10)

(1,2)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following

val pairs = lines.flatMap(x => x.split("\n") )

Good luck!